# Querying EOSIO system contract table

Tags: cleos, eosjs, eosio.system

How do I query an EOSIO system contract table ?

As a learning challenge, I am trying to figure out how to calculate the amount of EOS votes cast and aggregate attributes of vote.

Can I use **eosjs** to do this ?

I can't figure out where all this information is documented. EOS dev portal seems to be missing this information all together.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

System tables are not (yet) well documented. You have to browse the source code.

E.g. for voters you will find table `eosio voters` here:
https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/905e7c85714aee4286fa180ce946f15ceb4ce73c/contracts/eosio.system/eosio.system.hpp#L115

`cleos -u https://eu.eosdac.io get table eosio eosio voters` will return the first rows.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options two read any table (whether system table or table of another contract) by connecting to a public node:

- cleos `get table` call: https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cleos/reference#cleos-get-table
- rcp api `get_table_rows` call https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/reference#get_table_rows

Comment: Sure, this is well mentioned in EOS dev portal. But what I am looking for is information about what tables exists, and how to find the correct source (table) for a piece of information like voters.